# Huge eps file in Export with ListPlot and Filling

Tags: export, plotting, filling

I'm trying to export and eps file from a plot which contains a ListPlot with Filling

```
n = 1024;
x = Table[N[xdum], {xdum, 0, 1, 1/n}];
y = Cos[2 \[Pi] x];
ListPlot[{x, y}\[Transpose], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
Filling -> 0]
```

the dimension of the file is huge. Does anyone have some idea to overcome this problem? I was trying to use Rasterize and then Show, but I can not get the right image scaling.

Comment: What do you mean by "huge"? Also, is there a reason for using `ListPlot` rather than `Plot`?

Comment: ListPlot together with Filling produces per each point a vertical line used to fill the graph. When a lot of points are used the exported vector images, e.g. eps, is a huge file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works,

```
  plot=ListPlot[{x, y}\[Transpose], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
    Filling -> 0];
  Export[ "test.eps"  , Rasterize[plot, ImageSize -> 1000]];
```

The file size is reduced from 140k ( hardly "huge" ) to 30k, with a noticeable loss of quality.

If you are concerned with the *displayed size* of the figure that is normally dealt with in whatever application you use to import the eps.